# Why is $\left\{T^n x|n\geqslant 0\right\}$ dense in $X$ iff $x\in\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}\bigcup_{k\geqslant 0}T^{-k}U_n$?

Tags: ergodic-theory

In Walters' *An Introduction to Ergodic Theory* I found the following Theorem and proof (p. 29):

> > **Theorem 1.7.** Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $\mathfrak{B}(X)$ the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $X$ and let $m$ be a probability measure on $(X,\mathfrak{B}(X))$ such that $m(U)>0$ for every non-empty open set $U$. Suppose $T\colon X\to X$ is a continious transformation which preserves the measure $m$ and is ergodic. Then almost all points of $X$ have a dense orbit under $T$, i.e. $\left\{x\in X|(T^nx)_{n=0}^{\infty}\text{ is a dense subset of }X\right\}$ has measure one.

PROOF. Let $\left\{U_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a base for the topology of $X$. Then
$$
\left\{T^nx|n\geqslant 0\right\}
$$
is dense in $X$ iff
$$
x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_n.
$$
Since $T^{-1}(\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_n)\subset \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_n$ and $T$ is measure-preserving and ergodic we have $m(\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_n)=0$ or $1$. Since $\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_n$ is a non-empty open set we have $m(\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_n)=1$. The results follows.

---

Hello, I have two questions to this proof.

1.) Why is $\left\{T^nx|n\geqslant 0\right\}$ dense in $X$ iff $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_n$?

Edit: I think maybe I can try to answer this question by myself.

$A_x:=\left\{T^nx|n\geqslant 0\right\}$ is dense in $X$ if any neighbourhood $N$ in $X$ contains a point out of $A_x$. So let $N\subset X$ be an arbitrary neighbourhood in $X$, then for a $m\in\left\{0,1,2,...\right\}$, and an open set $O$ it is $a:=T^mx\in O\subseteq N$. $O$ can be written as $O=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$ for a subset $I\subseteq\left\{0,1,2,...\right\}$, so it is $a\in\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$, i.e. $a\in U_i$ for at least one $i\in I$. i.e. $x\in T^{-m}U_i$. From this it follows that $x\in\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_i$. Because we do not know which set of the base it is, we build the intersection. So if $A_x$ is dense in $X$, then each point of $A_x$ is in a union $\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_i$ for any $i\in\left\{0,1,2,3,...\right\}$ which is in any case true if $x\in\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq 0}T^{-k}U_n$.

2.) Why is it enough that $T^{-1}(\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_n)\subset \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_n$, isn't it necessary that $T^{-1}(\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_n)= \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{-k}U_n$ in order to use the ergodicity?

Edit: I think I can answer that by myself, too, now. One has to use an equivalent formulation of ergodicity: 
It is 
$$
T^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{k\geqslant 0}T^{-k}U_n\right)\subset\bigcup_{k\geqslant 0}T^{-k}U_n=:A
$$
and (because $T$ is measure-preserving)
$$
m\left(T^{-1}A\right)=m\left(A\right),
$$
so both sets are equal almost surely, i.e.
$$
m(T^{-1}A\Delta A)=0,
$$
so it is $m(A)=0$ or $m(A)=1$.

Because $T$ is continious and $U_n$ is open (because it's in the base), $T^{-k}U_n$ is open for any $k\geqslant 0$. So the countable union is open, too. Moreover, the union isn't empty, because each such union contains a point out of $\left\{T^nx|n\geqslant 0\right\}$ because of the density of that set in $X$. So it is $m(A)>0$, i.e. $m(A)=1$.

Why does now follow the result?
Do not see this last step. Can you explain that, pls? Maybe it's very easy and I simply do not see.

Comment: re question 1, the condition states that for this $x$, given a point $y$ and any neighbourhood $U$ of $y$ then $\exists k.T^k(x) \in U$. i.e. $\{T^k(x)\}_{k=0,...} \cap U \ne \emptyset$

Comment: @David Holden I added my idea concerning my first question. Used the characterization of "dense" via neighbourhoods.

Comment: Now added my idea to question 2.

Comment: Do not see how the result follows from $m(\bigcup_{k\geqslant 0}T^{-k}U_n)=1$.